# How would I print the largest number in an array and then move it to the end of the sequence?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written some code that asks the user how many numbers they want to input. The program then prints that number of statements asking for a number in each new line and then prints out the array at the end. How would I print the largest number and then on new line print the array sequence with that number at the end? Something like this for example:

How many numbers would you like to enter? 6

Please enter number 1: 10

Please enter number 2: 8

Please enter number 3: 3

Please enter number 4: 5

Please enter number 5: 2

Please enter number 6: 9

The largest number is: 10

New List: 8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 10

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i, count = 0;
    int numArray[4000];

    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter? : ";
    cin >> count;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << i+1 << " : ";
        cin >> numArray[i];
    }


    //cout << "The largest number is: " << largestNumber << endl;
    cout << "New list: ";
    for (i=0; i< count; i++)
    {
        cout << numArray[i];
        if (i < count - 1)
            cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the larges number in the array:

```
int numArray[4000];
int count = 4000;

int largest = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    if (largest_temp < numArray[i]){
        largest = numArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would that go into my code because I get redeclaration errors?

Comment: @Austinomical2 Ideally, nowhere. Rather, continually check for larger values during your input loop, retaining the index where it resides for later use to perform the rotation to the end of the sequence.

Comment: I am kinda new to C++ so I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: @Austinomical2 I mean, you're reading the values in a loop. While doing so, remember the array  index of the largest value you read. Later, you'll use that to shift everything above that in the array "left" one slot, moving the index value to the last slot and you're done.

Comment: @gabe I know I need to use a loop to swap X times, but only swap if the number on the left is bigger than the number on the right. But I don't know where it goes or how to do it

Comment: @Austinomical2 no, you don't need to swap conditionally (condition being, "f the number on the left is bigger"). The condition of "who is largest" is settled once your input loop is done and you've tracked which index refers to the largest element . All that remains is stashing that element off to a temporary, moving everything *after* that element down (left) one element in the sequence, then storing that value as the last in the array. To that you need (a) a loop, or (b) a standard library function that will do it for you. Either way, that's the basic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forget fixed-size array. Makes no sense and you might overflow. Replace `int numArray[4000];` with `std::vector<int> numArray;`, have an `#include <vector>`, and it'll work out of the box.

You can get the max element from a vector using:

```
auto largestNumberIt = std::max_element(numArray.begin(), numArray.end());
int largestNumber = *largestNumberIt;
```

You can erase an element from a vector using either `erase` or `remove` (it's not clear what you'd like to do to duplicates) and push the element to the end of `numArray` using `numArray.push_back(largestNumber);`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: thanks for spotting, fixed. Actually, OP might need the iterator as well as the value (depending on whether only single element is to be moved), so I've added both.